# Finding the constant for the particular solution to $y''(x) + y(x) = 2^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I'm really confused on this problem. Right now, I'm solving for the particular solution of:

$y''(x) + y'(x) = 2^x$

My test solution was $A^x$, and I got

$yp(x) = 2^x/(ln(A)^2 + 1)$

My problem here is that the solution in the book makes it so that A equals 2. I have no idea how they solved for A. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The DE in the title does not match the DE in the post. Please, fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The "test solution" should be $a \cdot 2^x$, not $A^x$.  You want the same exponential multiplied by a constant coefficient.

Comment: Is this the same idea as solving an equation using the Method of Undetermined Coefficients only it's a more advanced form? Or is it an entirely different topic?

Comment: It is exactly Undetermined Coefficients.  It's just that the exponential is written as $2^x$ rather than $\exp(cx)$.